# Trying to remember the name of a series from probably the 70s or 80s

Tags: story-identification

When I was younger, I got a book series from my grandma. I cannot, for the life of me, remember the name of the series. Here's what I remember:

Children are born through a new form of magic. The "old way" has been banned. Of course, our main character is born illegally through the "old way". Because of this, his father is banished to be a watcher, and turned into a stone statue overlooking a desert.

The main character runs off, and finds out that he is a conduit for magic, meaning that he can be used to channel magic.

I believe he ends up becoming part of a military group, and somehow ends up in the big capital city.

Comment: I guess it was in English? Do you remember how may books the series contained? Any covers maybe?

Comment: @Marzipanherz It was an English series. I want to say either a British or Australian publisher. 3 books that I remember and the covers were standard 80s-ish fantasy covers. I don't remember the specific details.